# Calculate the probability using binomial distribution for a conditional statement

Tags: probability

The probability of a defective item being produced is .3 out of 1 or 30%.  Of the next 20 items produced what is the probability that at least 10 are defective?

so $p(x\geq 10)$ or "the probability that x is greater than or equal to 10" appears to be what I am looking for. which can be represented as $1-p(x\leq 9)$

I know the **binomial distribution** as:

$$b(x;n,p)={n\choose x}(p^x)(q^{n-x})$$

where $x$ is number out of $n$ total trials and $p$ is probability of success.
$q$ is simply $1-p$.

In this example I find $n=20$, $p=.3$, and $q=.7$ however I am confused what the appropriate value for $x$ should be.  If I was looking for the probability of exactly 10 defective items I would simply plug 10 in for $x$ along with the other values for this case this would not work though.

Would the following method supply the correct probability?

$$1-b(9;n,p)-b(8;n,p)-...-b(0;n,p)$$

Comment: It looks good from here. $1$ minus the probability that there are nine errors, minus the probability that there are eight errors, etc.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure this method made sense since it required a great deal more effort to calculate in comparison to something like $p(x=10)$

Comment: @Integrator was that irony?